# JPA Criteria - Fetch child entities instead of root

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

Lets say we have 2 mapped and related entities: `Foo` -> `Bar`. `Foo` holds the FK to the `Bar`. The point is, that using `JPA Criteria Api` I need to `INNER JOIN` these tables and fetch all `Bar` entities. How can I achieve that without mapping declaring reverse relation?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9802717/using-projections-in-jpa-2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AVolpe thanks for pointing out `select`

Now thats how to do it:

```
CriteriaQuery<Bar> query = b.createQuery(Bar.class);

Root<Foo> root = query.from(Foo.class);

query.where(b.equal(root.get("bar").get("id"),"10219431"));
Selection<? extends Bar> join = root.join("Bar",JoinType.INNER);
query.select(join);
Bar b=getEntityManager().createQuery(query).getResultList().get(0);
```

This query gets `Bar` after `INNER JOIN` with `Foo` by FK stored in `Foo` (`Bar` is property of `Foo`)